# using Uniitest.TestResult.wasSuccessful() to chqcke if test has passed or not

Tags: python, python-unittest

In Python unittest framework we want to do some check after every test case. If it was succesful or not and if its not succussful we want to do some action.

I am trying to explore `Unittest.TestResult.wasSuccessful()`, but it returns 'True' even of test has passed. Here is example and output. As my `test_addNumbers` has failed it should return False

```
import unittest
class SampleClass(unittest.TestCase):
    result = unittest.TestResult()

    def setUp(self):
        print 'setup'

    def tearDown(self):
        print self.result.wasSuccessful()
        print 'tearDown'

    def test_addNumbers(self):
        a = 10
        b = 20
        c = a + b
        print c
        self.assertEqual('fo'.upper(), 'FOO')

    def test_addNumbers_new(self):
        p = 20
        q = 20
        r = p + q
        print r
        return r  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(SampleClass)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=1).run(suite)
```

Output:

> import unittest setup 30
>
> Failure Expected :'FO' Actual   :'FOO'
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\a4tech\Documents\WorkSpace\Vanilla_Python.git\Kiran_Test\SampleUnitTest.py",
> line 19, in test_addNumbers
> self.assertEqual('fo'.upper(), 'FOO') AssertionError: 'FO' != 'FOO'
>
> **True**
>
> tearDown
>
> setup
>
> 40
>
> **True**
>
> tearDown

Comment: your program does not output "True ... tearDown ... setup ... 40 ... True ... treaDown". Where does this output come from?

Comment: @Humbalan thaks for comment. its actually a console output. Please refer 'print' statement from the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A TestResult instance is returned by the TestRunner.run() method for
>   this purpose

(Found in https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult).

So you should change your last line in the code to

```
test_result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=1).run(suite)
```

and then evaluate `test_result`. Its value then is

```
<unittest.runner.TextTestResult run=2 errors=0 failures=1>
```